# A triangle $ABC$ with $c=60,l_c=10$ and $P=125$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A triangle $ABC$ is given with $c=60,l_c=10$ and $P=125$, where $AB=c$, $l_c$ is the angle bisector of $\measuredangle C$ and $P$ is the perimeter. Find $a$ and $b$.
[image]
Here are my thoughts:

We have $\begin{cases}\dfrac{m}{n}=\dfrac{b}{a}\\l_c^2=ab-mn\end{cases}.$ From the first equation we can get $$\dfrac{m+n}{n}=\dfrac{a+b}{a}$$ or $$\dfrac{12}{n}=\dfrac{13}{a}.$$ Then we can substitute $l_c=10$ into the second equation to get $$100=ab-mn.$$ I am stuck here. Thank you in advance!
Katherine

Comment: What do you have to determine?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva, edited. I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length of angle bisector is given by

$\displaystyle l_c^2 = \frac{ab}{(a+b)^2} ((a+b)^2 - c^2)$

$a+b = 125-60 = 65, c = 60$

Leads to $\displaystyle 10^2 = \frac{ab}{65^2}(65^2-60^2)$

i.e., $ab = 676 \implies a(65-a) = 676$

We get a quadratic $a^2 - 65a + 676 = 0 \implies a = 13, 52$

So $a = 13, b = 52$ or $a = 52, b = 13$

Answer (score 1):

We are given the system of equations $$\begin{cases}m+n=60\\a+b=65\\m\cdot a=n\cdot b\\100=ab-mn\end{cases}$$

You can solve it, for instance, taking $m=60-n$ and $a=65-b$ into the third and fourth equations, which will yield two equations with two unknowns: $$\begin{cases}(60-n)\cdot (65-b)=n\cdot b\\100= (65-b)\cdot b-(60-n)\cdot n\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}n=60 - \frac{12}{13}\cdot b\\100= (65-b)\cdot b-(60-n)\cdot n\end{cases}$$ Where the last equation is a quadratic in $b$ after substituting the first equation. This will yield $b$. You can solve for $a$ analogously.

I got

> $(a,b,m,n)=(13,52,48,12)$ or $(a,b,m,n)=(52,13,12,48)$